# How could I redirect nginx request based on the URL first header

Tags: linux, nginx

I have 3 app servers which are handled by nginx server.

```
upstream he {
server h1.abc.example.com;
server h2.abc.example.com;

}
```

How could I redirect requests request based on the some header value?Eg

```
 abc-h1.abc.example.com should go to server 
h1.abc.example.com
 def-h1.abc.example.com should go to server 
h2.abc.example.com
```

where `-h1.abc.example.com` is going be same for all requests.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx can certainly do that, you would just need to specify each host header (`server_name`) and separate the upstreams to assign one for each host.

An nginx server snippet like this might work (off the top of my head and untested):

```
upstream one { server h1.abc.example.com; }
upstream two { server h2.abc.example.com; }

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name abc-h1.abc.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass one;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name def-h1.abc.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass two;
    }
}
```

There are also other proxy handlers (`fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`, `scgi_pass`, `memcached_pass`) if you would like to send traffic to something that is not an HTTP endpoint

EDIT:  fix erroneous `server_name`